# error: The argument type 'FirebaseApp' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Firebase'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Future<void> main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final FirebaseApp app = await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp(app:app)));
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  FirebaseApp app;

  MyApp({this.app});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page',app:app),
    );
  }
}
```

I had issue that show up when compiling, it shows error: The argument type 'FirebaseApp' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Firebase'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [tingting_chat] lib\main.dart:28). How to fix it?

Comment: You don't have to pass the firebase app instance down the Widget tree.

Comment: How can I fix it? @HuthaifaMuayyad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
}
```

in app's gradle (at the end of file):

```
dependencies {
    ....
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

is project's gradle:

```
   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```